# RequestLocalizationOptions does not contain a definition for ApplyCurrentCultureToResponseHeaders

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to add support for Localization in a razor app following this [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1) but ApplyCurrentCultureToResponseHeaders is not recognized.

Is there any other way to persist the culture in the Url on navigation other than this ?

```
app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    ApplyCurrentCultureToResponseHeaders = true
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which `RequestCultureProvider` are you using?

You can use `RouteDataRequestCultureProvider` and a route with a pattern containing culture such as `{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}`

The `ApplyCurrentCultureToResponseHeaders` attribute will be in 5.0 and is not in 3.1. See [Add Content-Language header in localization middlewware](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/commit/e9179bacd7f997a51f9619511985671e0c131a11#diff-fb503ccc4e0f5cec82dc653050d5e67a)

Hope that helps.